# Digits after the decimal point are gone after returning from another function

Tags: c, mean

I'm a new beginner for programming and recently I am doing some homework in the Schools. The content of the homework is calculate the mean value of a set of data. Below is my code. I found out that the correct value is 93.974998, but the value shown from terminal is only 93.000000.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stats.h"
int findmean(unsigned char *ptr, float count);

int main() {

  unsigned char test[SIZE] = {34, 201, 190, 154,   8, 194,   2,   6,
                              114, 88,   45,  76, 123,  87,  25,  23,
                              200, 122, 150, 90,   92,  87, 177, 244,
                              201,   6,  12,  60,   8,   2,   5,  67,
                                7,  87, 250, 230,  99,   3, 100,  90};

    float mean = 0;
    float length_data = SIZE;
    
    mean = findmean( &test[0] , length_data);
    printf(" mean of the data is %f \n", mean );

    return 0;
}

int findmean(unsigned char *ptr, float count){

    float total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            
            total += *ptr;
            ptr++;
                    
    }
    printf("count is %f\n", count);
    
    return total/count;
}
```

If I change the code, instead of dividing the total value in the `findmean` function, but in the `printf` function like `printf(" mean of the data is %f \n", mean/lenght_data );`, then the answer will be correct.

I just didn't get it, where is the problem? Could somebody where I did wrong?

BTW, I am using geany and GCC version is 9.4.0, in case anyone want to know.

Comment: `int` doesn't have a decimal point.

Comment: You are returning an `int`.

Comment: For future reference code we cannot compile is unhelpful (to )_your_ cause).  It seems that `SIZE` is probably defined in `stat.h` but is not required in any event.  Remove it from the declaration of `test`: `unsigned char test[] = ...` then `int float length_data = sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test) ;`.  Whilst the issue is clearly that `findmean()` returns an `int`, your approach to data types is rather "random" and ill-considered. `length_data` for example should be an integer as should the `findmean()` `count` parameter - given that you then use it in an integer for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Return a *floating point* type, not `int`**

```
// int findmean(unsigned char *ptr, float count);
...
// int findmean(unsigned char *ptr, float count){

float findmean(unsigned char *ptr, float count);
float findmean(unsigned char *ptr, float count){
```

**`float` vs. `double`**

Best to use `double` as the default floating point type in C.  Both have limited precision.  The "correct value ist 93.974998" does print when `float` is used, but mathematically the correct answer is 93.975.  Use `double` unless there is a specific need to use `float`.

**Advanced**

Below is how I would have coded the *mean* calculation.

```
// Use `double` return type.
// Array length in `size_t` - not too wide, not to narrow type for arrays sizing.
// Length first to allow for diagnostics on ptr[]
// Use `const`  to indiacte the refeneced data in `ptr[]` does not change.
double findmean_alt(size_t count, const unsigned char ptr[count]) {
  // Accumulate the integer sum of `unsigned chars in a wider integer
  unsigned long total = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    total += ptr[i];  // Index into the data with `i`
  }

  printf("total is %lu\n", total);
  printf("count is %zu\n", count);

  // Perform the division with `double` math
  return 1.0 * total / count;
}
```

... and called it

```
// mean = findmean( &test[0] , length_data);
// Declare `mean` and initialize in one step.
double mean = findmean_alt(sizeof test/ sizeof test[0], test);
```